# Зачем в данном случае возвращать false?

Tags: jquery

Объясните, зачем в данном случае возвращать false? Работает ведь и без него.

```
$(function () {
    var $page = $('html, body');
    $('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
        var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
        $page.animate({
            scrollTop: $(href).offset().top
        }, 1000, function () {
            $(window).location.hash = href;
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Чтобы отключить стандартное поведение поведение браузера при клике на ссылку, указывающую на элемент на этой странице.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Многие события автоматически влекут за собой действие браузера.
>
> Например:
>
> 1. Клик по ссылке инициирует переход на новый URL.
> 2. Нажатие на кнопку «отправить» в форме – отсылку ее на сервер.
> 3. Двойной клик на тексте – инициирует его выделение.
>
> Если мы обрабатываем событие в JavaScript, то зачастую такое действие
>   браузера нам не нужно. К счастью, его можно отменить. Отмена действия
>   браузера
>
> Есть два способа отменить действие браузера:
>
> 1. Основной способ – это воспользоваться объектом события. Для отмены действия браузера существует стандартный метод event.preventDefault().
> 2. Если же обработчик назначен через onсобытие (не через addEventListener), то можно просто вернуть false из обработчика.

[Источник javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/default-browser-action)